# writing bit sequence in ASCII format MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ascii, bit

I'm trying to write some bits sequence in a compact format in Matlab to test my golomb-rice compressions code. It's a test for the C code. It's kind of 'faking it' in Matlab because it doesn't make sense to have bit operations. But it's for a test. I have something like '10111' and would like to write it to one character into a text file and then see what compression i achieve. I cannot find a way to write a bit sequence to ASCII in matlab. Any help?

Comment: Just to clarify: for example for `'01100001'`, would you like to write `'a'` to a text file?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to save your `1`s and `0`s in "binary" format not as text consisting of characters '1' and '0'. Here's an example how to do it:

```
filename = 'test.bin';
x = randi([0 1], 1, 10*8);
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fwrite(fid, x, 'ubit1');
```

The `'ubit1'` flag tells the `fwrite` function to interpret the vector `x` as 1-bit numbers.

In the above example, the resulting file size is exactly 10 Byte.